# How to have Hyper-v and VirtualBox together in the same PC Host? (not side by side)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have hyper-v with some vms and I installed VirtualBox for old OSs becauses it handles it better.

Unfortunately I'm having the known System_Service_Exception when starting a instance in VirtualBox

The solution is to deactivate HyperV but I would like to know if there is an option to have them both in the samve host computer.

Important to mention I don't want them running instances at the same time, I just wanted to have the ability to use hyperv or virtual box when I need

thanks

Comment: You only have to uninstall Hyper-V if you want to run 64-but operating system on a Virtual Box VM.  Otherwise if that’s what you want, what you want, is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only disable Hyper-V at boot, since it loads under the OS.  The "host" OS is actually a special virtual machine running on top of Hyper-V.

```
C:\>bcdedit /copy {current} /d "No Hyper-V" 
The entry was successfully copied to {*xxxx*}. 

C:\>bcdedit /set {*xxxx*} hypervisorlaunchtype off 
The operation completed successfully.
```

This gives you a boot menu where you can pick if you want to start with Hyper-V or not.